# return to the top of a loop

Tags: python

At `print("you dont have that many cards!")` i want the while loop to start over from

```
print("how many cards in heap no:", n, end="")
```

instead of breaking. How can this be done?

```
y = []
def cardHeaps():
    global cards
    n = 1
    while int(cards) > 0:
        print("how many cards in heap no:", n, end="")
        x = int(input("? "))
        cards = int(cards)
        if x > cards:
            print("you dont have that many cards!")
            break
        y.append(x)
        cards -= int(x)
        print(cards, " cards left")
        n += 1
        if cards <= 0:
            print("out of cards!")
            break
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) instead of `break`.

[Python docs on continue](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Hi @jacob, considering the OP asked how to go back to the top of the loop, continue would not do this right? It would complete the rest of the loop then move to next iteration: so how would you jump back to the top of the loop?

Answer (score 12):

Use `continue` instead of `break`.